# Encrypting large files in JavaScript & storing in S3 efficiently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encryption, amazon-s3

I have a UI which uploads files to s3 using pre-signed urls (gets the pre-signed urls from the server). It works quite nicely, except now there's a requirement to add one more layer of encryption on top (in-case the bucket got exposed by mistaken policies).

I understand there are ways to encrypt at the JavaScript layer using asymmetric keys, but it seems I've to read the file completely in memory, encrypt and then send. So if I upload 1GB, it will crash the browser/tab.

So is there an efficient way around this? I right now just use the `$http` angular service to upload the file. It's capable of handling 1GB files on its own - it seems to internally break the file into chunks & send it across.

I wasn't sure how to emulate that chunk behavior on my own. I can make use of `File.slice()` to read a part & encrypt. However the pre-signed url will upload it as a single entity. The next part will only replace the first one. Not sure how to combine multi-part upload with pre-signed urls.

I was also wondering if there's anyway to intercept the chunks that the `$http` service sends out, encrypt the body & then let them go again?

If there are no options, I would have to fall back to simply uploading the file to the server side, encrypt & push it to S3.

Comment: Did you use multipart update? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property

Comment: I explored briefly. But, to use the SDK we need credentials, right? I know we can get temporary credentials passed - but that's not as safe as a signed url which restricts upload only to one (dynamic) key. I've seen AWSIngonito referred in many places - but didn't check. What's the best way to use it? @D.Dimitrioglo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had asked this question assuming I could encrypt large files using public key encryption. I've seen a few strings getting encrypted in JS using public key, hence assumed I could replicate the logic for a large file.

Turns out, encrypting a large file using public/private keys isn't feasible. It would require firstly a huge key itself &/or would be time consuming to de/encrypt (even if chunked).

So, in the end I followed the industry practice - which was to generate a symmetric key & encrypt the object, and then encrypt the symmetric key using my public. Which turns out what AWS does all along with aws:kms  data-keys.

Once I resolved to using symmetric keys, I couldn't do it in the JS layer. I pushed it all the server. Transferring the file to the server & then to S3 again is not as slow as a I perceived.

Comment: Did you get a proper solution for this?

Comment: Using asymmetric keys for encrypting large files isn't feasible. They keys itself become massive in length.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Cognito Identity Pool
2. Get tmp credentials use `getCredentials` function
3. Use aws-sdk library and [createMultipartUpload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createMultipartUpload-property) method

function example:

```
function getCredentials() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const cognitoIdentityPoolId = 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx';
    let cognitoIdentityId = '';

    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: cognitoIdentityPoolId
    });

    AWS.config.credentials.get(err => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      cognitoIdentityId = AWS.config.credentials.identityId;

      let cognitoidentity = new AWS.CognitoIdentity();

      cognitoidentity.getCredentialsForIdentity({
        IdentityId: cognitoIdentityId
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(data.Credentials);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more info on Cognito? Seems like it will add a login functionality? A registered used, once logged in has his/her session tokens to perform AWS tasks?